# CSS Content style

Tags: html, css, sass

Have the following CSS/SCSS for my labels, however, the **label.req:before** is not applying the color attr. Does anyone know if it is possible modify the color of the content I'm inserting?

```
label {
     display:block;
    font-size: $tiny;   
}

label.req:before {
        content: "*";
        color:$red!important;
}
label:after {
        content: ": ";
}
```

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to modify the color of the content you are inserting. Your issue is most likely with the variable or the quotes surrounding it. (check if you need those quotes)

As of a month or so ago you can check out pseudo-elements in the chrome web inspector. Take a look at your source code using it and you should be able to fix this in a second

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, totally was the quotes.....I think I need more coffee.

Comment: Ill award you the answer when SO allow me. Cheers